# java Runtime.getRunTime().exec & wildcards?

Tags: java, shell, command, wildcard, runtime.exec

i'm trying to remove junk files by using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec();
```

it works fine as long as i do not use wildcards, i.e. this works:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/rm -f specificJunkFile.java");
```

while the following throws back "No such file or directory":

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/rm -f *.java");
```

i should be able to do all the nice things as outlined [here](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html), right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might I suggest that you let Java do this for you?

- Use file.listFiles() to get the list of files
- Use file.getName().contains(string) to filter them if needed
- iterate over the array performing file.delete()

Advantage: improved portability, saves the cost of an exec()

Comment: How do you use wild cards in general. Leave the rm etc. Let's say I have my own binary and I have to launch that from a java code. How would you do that?

Comment: The first two bullets are the handling of the `*`, the third corresponding to the `rm`. So you need to know what part of the string is a filename pattern, but otherwise you can stitch together any command line using the list of the files that you get from `listFiles()` (provided your external command accepts multiple filenames, of course).

Answer (score 16):

After a lot of searching I found this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/423573/java/java/Passing-wilcard-Runtime-exec-command

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "rm /tmp/ABC*" });
```

Comment: This assumes that you are running on a system for which the command interpreter `sh` is available. Which makes it somewhat non-portable.

Answer (score 9):

Those are Bash wildcards. They are interpreted within the Bash shell. You are running rm directly, so there is no shell to interpret the `*` as 'all files'.

You could use bash as the command. e.g.:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path-to/bash -c \"rm *.foo\"")`

Comment: okay i'm doing:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"rm *.foo\"");
and i'm getting:
ERROR>*.foo": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
this i do not understand... the escapes are correct aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "gunzip *.gz" });

Answer (score 0):

1. Use exec( String [] { cmd , arg1 , arg2...)
2. Here's a full example to get the result as a String : [Link](http://franckbehaghel.free.fr/java/exec-within-java.php).