# Create orphan branch and rm -rf in JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm using JGit to create an orphan branch as [outlined on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/905571).

What is the equivalent command `rm .git/index; git clean -fdx` in JGit?

I'm able to create a new branch normally without the `--orphan` argument, but am unsure how to apply it as well as the command to delete the branched files, which you would do normally as `git rm -rf .`

I know that I can checkout an orphan branch, will it achieve the same thing? `git.checkout().setOrphan()`. Is it as simple as `git.getRepository().getWorkTree().delete()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there is no direct equivalent to `git clean -fdx` in JGit. Your best bet is to manually prepare the work directly and index after you have created the orphan branch with JGit. Use the Java file system APIs to [recursively delete all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240519/delete-files-with-same-prefix-string-using-java) from the work directory. Make sure not to delete the .git folder. And finally delete `.git/index`.