# Elasticsearch REST api through curl not working from java.runtime.exec

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch, libcurl

I have a java app in which I'm just reading a file and inserting the data into the elasticsearch index.

Here is the code I 'm using.

```
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        line = in.readLine();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Command: curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/esensor/data' -d '{ \"temp\": \""+line+"\" }'");
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/esensor/data' -d '{ \"temp\": \""+line+"\" }'");
            p.waitFor();

            BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
            }
            break;
        }
        in.close();
```

But this is not working. Curl is giving this error.

```
curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "temp"

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "17.35757"
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

But see I have printed the command which I'm executing. If I manually copy paste that in console then everything working fine. Why it is happening? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the elasticsearch's client?  [ElasticSearch Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486649/shell-bash-brace-expansion-with-javas-runtime-exec

Comment: @RC how it is related to my question??

Comment: @chengpohi I was just trying to do using exec. Cause using client will cause more memory consumption. In my case that chunk of code may run in 1000-10000 threads or more. So I was thinking if exec only may cause less memory consumption. May be I'm wrong. Is it not possible with runtime.exec?

Comment: I think you issue is braces `{}` interpretation try escaping them

Comment: @RC \{ is meaning less. Giving error. Invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

A key is in the error message from curl:

```
curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

The single quote before the protocol name there shows that curl gets that passed as part of the argument, and thus it doesn't work the way you want it to and instead it gives curl a malformed URL.

Comment: Can you please give me the correct command which I have to send in runtime.exec?? Please I cant find anything working.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec clearly does not support regular shell-style quoting. You better read up the details. I don't know it, I'm just interpreting what curl said...