# Using stdin "<" in java process builder

Tags: java, runtime

I am using process builder to execute some windows commands but I am not able to use the `stdin <` for reading a file. For example, reading the `myJOB` configuration xml to create a new job called `myJOB` is working fine in command prompt but not working in eclipse using process builder:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "url" create-job myJOB < myJOB_Config.xml
```

Any solutions...

Comment: `<` is interpreted by the shell. ProcessBuilder won't do that but I guess you could (don't. `redirectInput` is better) build a process that invokes a shell that executes the command. Like `bash -c "command here"`. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16486906

Answer (score 1):

Build your command without the `< myJOB_Config.xml`, then use [`ProcessBuilder.redirectInput(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput(java.io.File)).

> Sets this process builder's standard input source to a file.

Comment: I tried this...didn't work out. Instead of file, the ProcessBuilder gets  java.lang.ProcessBuilder@29be9e36 as argument, in turn throwing error

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's not much I can say, aside from you've not used the API correctly.

Comment: This is my code:  `code` java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "url" create-job myJOB pb1.redirectInput(new File("myJOB_Config.xml")) `code`

Comment: What you provided is not the whole code. The code would include something like `(new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "jenkins-cli.jar", "-s", url, "create-job", "myJOB")).redirectInput(File)` and some more code around to run the command and read output.