# Java runtime exec with scp command

Tags: java

This is a part of my code to copy files from local to a remote machine

```
try {
Process cpyFileLocal = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scp  " + rFile+"*.csv"     + " root@" + host + ":" + lFile);
InputStream stderr = cpyFileLocal.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
System.out.println("<ERROR>");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("</ERROR>");
int exitVal = cpyFileLocal.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
System.out.println("...." + cpyFileLocal.exitValue());
System.out.println("SCP COMMAND  "+"scp "+rFile+"*.csv" +"  root@"+host+":"+lFile);
System.out.println("Sending  complete...");
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

the output is...

```
<ERROR>

    /opt/jrms/rmsweb/transfer/cn00/outgoing/*.csv: No such file or directory
    </ERROR>

    Process exitValue: 1

    ....1

    SCP COMMAND  scp /opt/jrms/rmsweb/transfer/cn00/outgoing/*.csv root@10.50.1.29:/opt/jrms/transfer/incoming/
```

but when I run the command in terminal on the local machine, it works fine
and when I run **ll** the files are there

-rwxr-xr-x 1 freddie freddie  140 Apr 22 09:13 gc00cn00150420092629.csv*

-rwxr-xr-x 1 freddie freddie  105 Apr 22 09:13 gc00cn00150420122656.csv*

Any help please

Answer (score 2):

When you run command with in bash with wildcards like `*` in it, bash will expand that command and in your case, replaces `*.csv` with list of files terminating with `.csv`, but in your java program, this won't happen.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2112307/1805756), you can do following:

- Use file.listFiles() to get the list of files
- Use file.getName().contains(string) to filter them if needed
- Iterate over the array and perform `scp` or do it with whole list

or with thanks to [@James Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787186/java-runtime-exec-with-scp-command/29787440?noredirect=1#comment47706426_29787440) comment add `sh` before `scp` in your command.

Comment: the weird thing is using the same command, copying files from remote to my local machine *.csv works fine, however, using *.csv from Local to remote, that's when the issue occur.  Ant ideas?  thanks

Comment: It's because scp will interpret that command at remote server (and probably in a bash), and list of files will be expanded on that host, not locally. But when you try local to remote file exchange, there is no bash to expand it.

Comment: Or you could just add an "sh" shell command before the " scp "

Comment: @SAM thanks for your inputs..seems to be working now

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java 7 and above you should use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and in the `ProcessBuilder` you can specipied the execution directory:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scp", rFile+"*.csv", "root@" + host + ":" + lFile);
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory("directory where the csv files located");
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/423573/java/java/Passing-wilcard-Runtime-exec-command), you should try:

```
Process cpyFileLocal = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh","-c", "scp  " + rFile+"*.csv"     + " root@" + host + ":" + lFile});
```

I tested with `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`, both copied the files over successfully